# Define scenarios for cucumber testing of login procedure in two levels

Tags: javascript, meteor, cucumber, gherkin

I'm trying to write a `feature` file for user login of my meteor app (cucumber testing). There are two forms (main form and pin form) the user has to fill to login successfully.

My problem is to define the scenarios as there are two form with valid/invalid input option for the user.

```
1. Click on sign in buttn
2. Type username and password
2.1. Invalid username/password
2.2. Valid username/password (then pin form is added to DOM)
2.2.1. Type pin number (pin form)
2.2.1.1. Pin correct -> show content
2.2.1.2. Pin incorrect -> show message
```

I started with this and it feels very bad. That's no DRY attempt...

Feature: Allow users to login and logout
    As a user of application
    I want to login and logout
    So that I can prove my identity and see data

```
Background:
    Given I am signed out

Scenario: Login with invalid username/password
    When I click on sign in link
    And I enter incorrect authentication information
    Then I should see a 'user not found error'

Scenario: Login with valid username/password and valid PIN
    When I click on sign in link
    And I enter my authentication information
    And Pin form is shown
    Then I should be logged in

Scenario: Login with valid username/password and invalid PIN
```

Comment: did you consider splitting this into two features? Login, `Given I am signed out` and scenarios `2.1` and `2.2` and entering the Pin, `Given I am signed in` ...

Answer (score 1):

It really shouldn't matter how your app works. Try

```
Scenario: Sign in
  Given I am registered
  When I sign in
  Then I should be signed in

Scenario: Sign in with bad credentials
  Given I am registered
  When I sign in with bad credentials
  Then I should be signed out
  And I should see an error
```

Features/Scenarios are all about capturing what you are doing and why its important. They should be oblivious to how you are doing something.